# Text breaking in the middle of word with apostrophe

Tags: html, css, angular

I'm just simply showing HTML from API in my app, but text is wrapping up in the middle of the word.

Example:

I just want to explain, what problem **I'**

**m** facing. Text should only wrap

in a space.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```html
<nobr>I'm</nobr>
```

for the words containing the apostrophe.
Attention: The  Tag is not standard HTML but supportet by many browsers.

Otherwise you could use use

```html
<div style="white-space: break-spaces;"> just want to explain, what problem I'm facing. Text should only wrap in a space.</div>
```

That should be supported.

You can find further Information [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/nobr) (about `<nobr>`) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) (css editing).

Comment: In case this Answer did not help you, you might like to post a minimal example.

Comment: <div [innerHTML]="cardItem.teaserHeadlineText">  </div>
The thing is, it's inserting text from API.

Comment: How do you render the content to HTML? What method?

Comment: @user17635560 Maybe the edit helps you. Take a look at the second link. You can find there additional information about how to wrap with css

Answer (score 0):

In case you're getting an unwanted line break at an apostrophe with a hyperlink like I did, I found that adding this fixed it.

```
white-space: nowrap;
```